# Conditional write item if attribute not equals with DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to do a conditional write/update using DynamoDB mapper when you want to have condition like: Write if attribute is not equal to X?
I want to do a conditional write that does something like this:

```
DynamoRecord record = mapper.load(DynamoRecord.class, hashKey);
if (record.getSomeAttr() != terminationValue) {
    mapper.save(newRecord);
}
```

The attribute always exists. It can have multiple values and represents a condition after which the updates to the record should stop.

I read [this article](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1JADUVTWF7SP2/Specifying-Conditional-Constraints-with-Amazon-DynamoDB-Mapper) and [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html) and a bunch of other posts but seems like only `==` operator is supported along with exists check. Is it possible to do a `!=` conditional write using a mapper? If so, any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks.

**Summary from @notionquest's answer**

1. Use `ComparisonOperator.NE`
2. If the attribute is a boolean, annotate it using `@DynamoDBNativeBoolean` for correct results while using `ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue().withBool(true))`. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBNativeBoolean.html) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use "withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE)" for NOTEQUALS condition. Refer the below example.

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
       Map expected = new HashMap();
       expected.put("Status", 
          new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue(status)).withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE));
saveExpression.setExpected(expected);
dynamoDBMapper.save(obj, saveExpression);
```

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked ComparisonOperator entirely. However, when I tried this solution, it didn't work as expected.
I have a record with `status = true`. Code that is something like `new DynamoDBSaveExpression().             
  withExpectedEntry("status", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue().withBool(true)))       .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE));`

This doesn't throw a ConditionalCheckFailedException, but throws when I change `NE` to `EQ`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Please define the boolean field as follows using DynamoDBNativeBoolean annotation.                    @DynamoDBNativeBoolean
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "status")
public Boolean getStatusCode() {
  return statusCode;
 }

Comment: what is the status object here ?

Answer (score -1):

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
Map expected = new HashMap();
expected.put("Status",new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue('NE')));
saveExpression.setExpected(expected);
dynamoDBMapper.save(obj, saveExpression);
```

Comment: Please add comment to your code to explain your answer and to make it more usefull

Comment: This will not work because you need to provide "what" value the expected Status update cannot be equal to.